# Bluetooth not working properly: can't find any device but is discoverable by other devices - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I have been troubling with bluetooth recently. I tried pairing my bluetooth mouse, but it won't find it. When I open my phone, it does see the mouse and it sees the bluetooth of my laptop. So my laptop is discoverable, but is not able to discover other devices. This has worked in the past, and I have tried another kernel but it won't work.

I tried:

- Using GUI application  `blueman` , same issue there
- `rfkill unblock bluetooth`, no hard or soft block
- `systemctl status bluetooth`, says that it is enabled

Does anyone have a idea/had a similar issue?

EDIT: added output of

```
lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
```

```
[    1.378111] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    5.080151] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.080222] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.080233] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.080239] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.080251] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.186357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.490597] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 42 week 52 2015
[    5.491569] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    5.491573] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    5.491575] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    5.491578] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    5.491580] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    5.491584] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    5.494661] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-17-16-1.sfi
[    5.510646] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    7.073177] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    7.073549] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1550221 usecs
[    7.073676] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    7.086547] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 12641 usecs
[    7.086922] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-17-16-1.ddc
[    7.089564] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    7.335695] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.335699] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.335708] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.937733] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.937737] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.937739] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11[    1.378111] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    5.080151] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.080222] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.080233] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.080239] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.080251] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.186357] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.490597] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 42 week 52 2015
[    5.491569] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    5.491573] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    5.491575] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    5.491578] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    5.491580] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    5.491584] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    5.494661] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-17-16-1.sfi
[    5.510646] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    7.073177] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    7.073549] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1550221 usecs
[    7.073676] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    7.086547] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 12641 usecs
[    7.086922] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-17-16-1.ddc
[    7.089564] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    7.335695] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.335699] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.335708] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.937733] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.937737] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.937739] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31, I added the output :)